# sum of first 2 terms and 6 terms of a GP are 7 and 9 respectively. Find sum of 8 terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Sum of first 2 terms and first 6 terms of a GP are 7 and 9 respectively.
>   Find sum of first 8 terms.

I have googled and went through the solution available in internet. answer is approximately 9.09. However, I am looking for a more simple way to solve this problem. Please suggest the shortest approach.

EDIT:

The approach I have found is provided below which is taken from [this website](http://www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=3047)

[screenshot of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If1AM.png)

I feel the answer is complicated because of the calculations involved. Looking for a shortcut method if any (for competitive examinations).

Comment: Please describe the approach you find too complicated and why you think there should be an easier one.

Comment: @RossMillikan adding the approach

Comment: @RossMillikan, edited the answer. please help

Comment: The linked approach seems the most direct way.

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for clarifying

Comment: The solution is easy in some sense for this example since one ended up needing to solve a quadratic in $r^2.$ A related problem with given numbers of terms different from 2 and 6 likely would not be so simple to find a power of $r$ to do the problem.